# Is there a way to detect if Java FX is using hardware acceleration?

Tags: java, javafx-2, hardware-acceleration

And related to that, is there a way to force Java FX to use hardware acceleration and bomb if it is unable to?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just found out:

You can run with `-Dprism.verbose=true` which will print what graphics pipeline it uses. "sw" or "j2d" for software and "d3d" or "es2" for hardware accelerated.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this hack

```
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
static String getCurrentGraphicsPipeline() {
    return com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.getPipeline().getClass().getName();
}
```

If you get back `"com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline"` then you're using software acceleration. All other values will mean that probably some form of hardware acceleration is being used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse as IDE, then you need to pass these VM arguments. You can add these VM arguments in the run Configurations.

Put these arguments there:
`-Dprism.verbose=true`

[image: Have a look at the image for more information]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set your graphics pipeline using the `-Dprism.order=es2` VM-option. You can replace es2 for the desired pipeline (d3d, sw, j2d).

Answer (score 0):

For software renderers, the SCENE 3D feature is disabled.

```java
if(Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D)) {
    // hardware accelerated renderer
} else {
    // software renderer
}
```