# Is it possible to enable hardware acceleration with Java FX on Windows 2008 server?

Tags: java, graphics, javafx-2, javafx, hardware-acceleration

As discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566379/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-java-fx-is-using-hardware-acceleration), it's possible to detect whether Java FX is using hardware acceleration by passing `-Dprism.verbose=true` as a system property. When I do this on my Java FX app on Windows 2008 Server R2, it is apparently falling back to the software rendering:

```
Prism pipeline init order: d3d j2d
Using t2k for text rasterization
Using dirty region optimizations
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Loading D3D native library ...
        succeeded.
Direct3D initialization failed
Wrong operating system version
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline: error initializing pipeline com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DPipeline
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DPipeline
```

My question is, is it possible to force hardware acceleration, say by fooling JFX into thinking I have a different operating system? I'm hoping it might Just Work if I could bypass the OS check somehow.

Comment: [Windows 2008 Server is not a supported platform for JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html).  Attempting to run JavaFX on Windows 2008 Server is not advised.

Answer (score 4):

It is fairly easy : -Dprism.forceGPU=true

Comment: This flag doesn't seem to do anything. I get the exact same log messages.

Comment: It just tries more hard than usual. If it cannot - than troubles are not avoidable...

Answer (score 3):

you can also define the order that javaFx tries to use like: -Dprism.order=es2,j2d.
You need it if you want OpenGl rendering on Windows

Comment: `WARNING: The prism-j2d pipeline should not be used as the software
fallback pipeline. It is no longer tested nor intended to be used for
on-screen rendering. Please use the prism-sw pipeline instead by setting
the "prism.order" system property to "sw" rather than "j2d".`

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have not installed DirectX.

Direct3D initialization failed..