# Why Java GUI (JavaFX) runs much slower in Linux (Ubuntu) than in Windows

Tags: java, performance, user-interface, ubuntu, javafx

Could you explain to me why a JavaFX based Java app is running so slow/laggy in Ubuntu than in Windows?

Does it have anything to do with OpenGL not activated for Ubuntu?
Currently I am running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and 16.04.

Comment: Some questions - is it everything JavaFX, or just some things? How about a completely empty window?  What language/languages are you using? Do you have Mesa/DRI drivers installed? Are you testing on the same machine, or at least similar specs?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966427/is-it-possible-to-enable-hardware-acceleration-with-java-fx-on-windows-2008-serv , and maybe include the output of running with `-Dprism.verbose=true`

Comment: yes everything is programmed with Java and JavaFX in Netbeans. I have no Mesa/DRI drivers installed. I am testing on the same machine with Windows installed in dual boot configuration.

Comment: Using the software renderer can certainly make JavaFX run slower. You can make sure this is really the case by enabling verbose prism output (see my second comment, or the linked question).

Comment: If you don't have hardware accelleration activated on Linux it may make sense to compare against Windows again with -Dprism.order=sw set so that you do not compare apples and oranges.