# Does JavaFX support eGPUs?

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to accellerate my MacMini (Thunderbolt 3, Mojave)
with an eGPU but I have to make sure this is supported by JavaFX. Has anybody tried this and can tell me whether this works in general and in particular with the above mentioned Mac configuration?
Michael

[1] https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208544

Comment: I'd try the javafx mailing list for this kind of question.

Comment: JavaFX historically used openGL but apple are moving to a new API called Metal. IIRC JavaFX is being enhanced to support this. JavaFX has a SW pipeline so you may not need GPU anyway. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: From Oracle's docs: "JavaFX supports graphic hardware acceleration on any certified Mac OS X system."  Also see this answer to test if your JavaFX is using hardware acceleration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14567612/5174436.

Comment: @Adam 1. I asked there before I posted here but I did not get an answer. 2. My JavaFX runs with the HW pipeline. That's not the problem. The problem is that the MacMini only has an internal Intel graphics which is too slow when I use a large screen.

Comment: @Matthew This statement from Oracle is from a time when eGPUs where not supported at all on Macs. Not even all Mac software can make use of them so I ask whether JavaFX on a Mac can.